# Making sense of predicted probabilities for multi-labeled problems

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm currently working on a multi-label classification problem using `scikit-learn`, and I'm having a bit of trouble learning how to get the predicted probabilities for each class/label - similar to what scikit-learn's `.predict_proba()` method does on binary classification tasks.

My `y` is a 100x10 2d array, having 10 unique classes, and I'm using scikit-learn's `ensemble.RandomForestClassifier()` as my classifier.

What I would like to do is just predict the probability that a set of given features belongs to one of the classes (noted below as `cl_`) in `y`. So basically I'm imagining an output similar to this:

```
cl_1 | cl_2 | cl_3 | cl_4 | cl_5 | cl_6 | cl_7 | cl_8 | cl_9 | cl_10
---------------------------------------------------------------------
 0.0 |  0.0 |  0.0 | 0.1  |  0.3 | 0.0  | 0.0  |  0.0 | 0.6  | 0.0
```

**NOTE:** I have fit the Random Forest classifier to the dataset and the `.predict()` method works as expected. However, the `.predict_proba()` method returns probabilities in the shape of *C x M*, where *C* is the number of unique classes, and *M* is the number of instances in the dataset.

**Clarification/Update:** Here's an actual `y` instance from my dataset:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1 0]
```

Using the `.predict_proba()` on `X_test` returns a 2d-array of shape 39 x 848,048 (where 39 is the number of unique classes and 848,048 is the number of instances). 
So in layman's terms, what I'm asking is: How do I make since of what `.predict_proba()` returns (insofar as the little chart above is concerned).

**NOTE:** This:

```
y_hat_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
print(y_hat_proba[0][1])
```

returns `[ 1.  0.]`

Comment: Is y your class variable.  And did you one-hot encode it or something?  In otherwords, is each class label a binary vector?  I don't understand why its 100 x 10.

Comment: Yea y was put through the preprocessing.MultiLabelBinarizer(). I use that because of the multiple labels. I used the 100 x 10 as an example - the 100 being an example number of instances, and the 10 being the 10 unique classes.

Comment: Can you post the example outputs for a few training examples?   Is it just that the columns don't sum to one?  Because it sounds like you would want a M x C ndarray as your output, right?

Comment: The dimensions you described are actually transposed.  It should be 848048x39.  Are you sure you're passing X_test in correctly (may need to transpose first).   Also, in terms of asking questions check out http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yea Garrett I noticed that too, went back and checked X and y, and everything thing is fine as far as the shapes go so I have no idea why the output is transposed.

Comment: Upvoted your coment Garrett because it helped lead to an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.predict_proba(X_test)` to get the probability per class on a new set of points. If you need a prediction for a single point, just make sure `X_test` has a single row.

The shape of the output should be in the shape [n_samples, n_classes] (in the test set).
[You can see the function's documentation.](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba)

Comment: I hate to add actual code to a question because I feel that it complicates things, but I think it's necessary for clarification in this case. I will edit my question with updates.

Comment: The output will not be [n_samples, n_features].   You may have misread the documentation

Comment: Apologies, it will be [n_samples, n_classes] if the input is not sparse. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

An update to this, since scikit-learn has advanced quite a bit over the years and this approach is more generalizable beyond predicting on a single sample:

Currently, `predict_proba()` returns an

> ndarray of shape (n_samples, n_classes), or a **list of such arrays**

per [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba) (currently sklearn v1.0). As such, a useful way I found to get the output to be the shape and form the OP is expecting (which was also what I was expecting) is to do the following:

```
# List of length n_labels comprised of numpy arrays each having shape (n_samples, n_classes)
predict_proba_output = model.predict_proba(features_test)

# Make into ndarray of shape (n_samples, n_labels, n_classes)
reshaped_proba_output = np.swapaxes(np.array(predict_proba_output), 0, 1)
```

Note that, using the scikit-learn syntax, `n_classes` means "cardinality of each target". So in the OP's case of all-binary targets, `n_classes=2`.